# Plaid API investment holdings don't have unique identifier

Tags: plaid

`/investments/holdings/get` does not return a unique identifier. So it does not seem possible to make local DB updates without wiping all existing holding data. Is there something I'm missing?

Sample response from Plaid:

```
{
    "account_id": "5d37rd4BdJkq1zZkR8XEI9ovVAn35Ph464637",
    "cost_basis": null,
    "institution_price": 15.24,
    "institution_price_as_of": null,
    "institution_value": 30.48,
    "iso_currency_code": "USD",
    "quantity": 2,
    "security_id": "3mg4qV4JZyckeZnYfgazubEhn8gLKkUeMVpx4",
    "unofficial_currency_code": null
}
```

Note that `account_id` + `security_id` is not a valid compound key. Plaid returns each "lot" of a holding, so there can be multiple holdings for the same security and account, as they would likely have different cost bases.

If Plaid is listening, it would be nice to add a unique `holding_id` to the response, which is surely being stored on Plaid's end, similar to `transaction_id`, `item_id`, or `account_id`.

Comment: If you want Plaid to "listen" then perhaps contact them directly.

Comment: @SolarMike already have!

Comment: @codeprose-sam Have you found out anything from Plaid? Perhaps you can write an answer to your question.